# How to decode URI string using javascript?

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to decode this string `%21%22%23%C2%A4%25%26%2F` to `!"#¤%&/` inside my `confirm` so it doesn't say the encoded string in the `confirm`, but the actual string. But how can I do this?

I tried something like this, but it doesn't work.

```
...
if(confirm('Are you sure you want to removed the JQL: ' + decodeStr(encoded_string_value))){
...
}

function decodeStr(strVal) {
    var decodeStr = '';
    if(strVal && typeof strVal === 'string') {
        // strip script/html tags
        decodeStr = strVal.replace(/<script[^>]*>([\S\s]*?)<\/script>/gmi, '');
        decodeStr = decodeStr.replace(/<\/?\w(?:[^"'>]|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*>/gmi, '');
        return decodeStr;
    }
}
```

Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: What is your actual string? or encoded string? Sample will help

Comment: It's in the question @HardikShah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try?

```
decodeURI(strVal)
```

or

```
decodeURIComponent(strVal)
```

Comment: You will need to use `decodeURIComponent("%21%22%23%C2%A4%25%26%2F")
//  '!"#¤%&/'`to get the wanted result.

Comment: @CarstenMassmann  Good call

Comment: Thanks! had only tried `decodeURI`... `decodeURIComponent` works!